# Fabric JS filters vs CSS Filters

Tags: javascript, html, css, fabricjs

We're working on porting a current solution implemented using HTML and CSS over to Fabric JS. The software in itself allows the users to move images around and apply some filters to them. In the HTML/CSS solution positioning is managed via CSS and Image effects through the CSS filter property. The user is allowed to change the Brightness and Contrast of the images.

The issue we've been having is that the CSS filter property seems to work multiplicatively whereas the Fabric filters seem to be additive. This results in these solutions behaving quite differently. For reference here's an image set to +33% brightness from its default value (be it 1, 100 or 0). As you can see this does not achieve the same result at all.

**CSS filter (`filter: brightness(1.33)` - Default is 1)**
[image]

**Fabric filter (`new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({ brightness: 0.33 });` - Default is 0)**
[image]

For reference, here's the default state of the image in both cases (I wouldn't say it's completely identical but it's definitely close enough).

**CSS Default (1 Brightness)**
[image]

**Fabric JS Default (0 Brightness)**
[image]

As stated above, it seems to me that the main difference is into how the filter is applied. Looks like CSS does this **multiplicatively** (the blacks stay black as it is 0 * something) whereas Fabric does this **additively** (blacks go up as it is 0 + something). Our main concern is to make both these approaches consistently (make them behave the same). Be it by making the CSS filter additive or the Fabric one Multiplicative. Ideally we'd like to make Fabric behave as CSS and not the other way around as CSS is our current solution and we'd like it to be seamless. The same issue goes for the Contrast filter (it seems).

Thanks in advance for everything!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great issue.

I suggest you open a ticket (I guess under a discussion) in the repo.

Filters are not my domain in fabric but the other contributors will find this interesting.

You can mention me and I'll spin up the discussion

Comment: Thank you! Will do! I've already solved my particular problem by creating a custom Brightness filter based on Fabric's one. Will post that solution as well to the GH issue.

Comment: Done! https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/discussions/8304